# Using MySQL variable in PHP Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli

When using a SET clause in a MySQL statement, mysqli->prepare returns false.

This MySQL statement will "prepare" okay:

```
$query = "  INSERT INTO log (channel, message, context, datetime)
              VALUES (?, 'testmsg', '{}', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); ";
  
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); // $stmt will be true
```

This statement will cause "prepare" to return false.

```
$query = " SET @Channel = ?;
           INSERT INTO log (channel, message, context, datetime)
           VALUES (@Channel, '', '{}', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); "
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); // $stmt will be false
```

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO log (channel, message, context, datetime) ' at line 2

Why can't prepare handle the SET operator in MySQL in this manner? I want to list all my variables (this example only has one but imagine one with 10+) at the top of my statement for readability instead of sprinkling them inside the mysql code. That's not very unreadable and difficult to debug.

Comment: With PDO classes you can use named parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only prepare one SQL statement at a time. But your $query contains two statements, separated by a semicolon. Split them apart, or just use this.

```php
$query = " INSERT INTO log (channel, message, context, datetime)
           VALUES (?, '', '{}', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); "
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
```

Comment: Agreed, there's really no reason for the `SET` call.

Comment: Uh that's too bad it only does one at a time.  The real reason is for readability. It's difficult having dozens of  question marks sprinkled throughout giant queries. It's difficult to troubleshoot and you have to take extra care of the ordering when binding.  oh well -- I guess this is the answer.

Comment: The reason you're struggling is because, in all honestly, `mysqli` is pretty terrible. PDO is a far better DB layer for the singular reason that you can *name* your placeholders. `?` is mysterious. `:channel` is not. If you're committed to mysqli you're going to need to get used to placeholder bindings really quickly, because if this irritates you going forward you'll never get anything done. Consider: This isn't unlike function arguments that don't have names either. In time you'll learn to deal.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `SET` for some reason, you can `SET` user-defined variables in a prepared statement. Then you can use those variables in a subsequent call. You just can't do both in one call.

```
// first use SET
$query = "SET @Channel = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
// ...bind parameters...
$stmt->execute();

// Then do a second call:
$query = "INSERT INTO log (channel, message, context, datetime)
           VALUES (@Channel, '', '{}', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); "
$mysqli->query($query); // no need for prepare()/execute() in this case
```

As long as you use the same connection for both calls, the user-defined variables will still have their value when you `INSERT`. There's no need to `SET` and then use the variables in the same call.